# Configurar Variáveis de Ambiente JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, variáveis-de-ambiente

Segue a configuração das minhas variáveis de ambiente:

```
PATH - C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

JRE_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
```

Eclipse reconhece as variáveis e executa os projetos normalmente (com TomCat, Jboss inclusive). Porém, após "limpar e construir" no Netbeans aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> **cmd não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou arquivo em lotes**

O que poderia ser? Obrigada. 
Obs.: Já fui em Ferramentas > Opções > Sem Proxy (em Definições de Proxy)

Comment: Já testou num prompt de comando os seguintes comandos: `javac` e `java`? Teste ai, se não funcionarem, as variáveis não foram corretamente configuradas.

Comment: Tem como mandar um print mostrando a variável PATH inteira?

Comment: @LINQ > não sei enviar print aqui

Comment: @Articuno > As classes compilam.

Comment: @MarianaDelfino posta no imgur e cola o link

Comment: @LINQ > https://i.imgur.com/dJzILjH.png                                                      > https://imgur.com/a/uPKQQ

Comment: @MarianaDelfino vê se tem c:\Windows\system32 na path

Comment: @LINQ - Ambiente para dev Java OK e Funcionando.